# Visual basic - txt as string for email script

Tags: email, vba

I'm trying to fix up a mailscript.

I pretty much need something like

```
cmBody = "c:\body.txt"
```

It's not that simple, but you get the idea.

The txt file is the content of the email.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Can you be more specific and detailed? you are running around the question... :$

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I want cmbody to contain the content of body.txt 

edit: I think I got it. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim contents As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    contents = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\test.txt", ForReading).ReadAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

This is the code I ended up using. (If any of you even understood the question)

```
Open "C:\body.txt" For Input As #intFile
strFile = Input$(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
Close #intFile
cmBody = strFile
```